# How to choose where exported project template appears?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Hopefully a very simple question:

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and am trying to export a windows forms project as a template. How do I choose where the exported template appears? When creating a new project, after having exported my template project, the template always appears under "Visual C#". I want it under "Visual C#->Windows". How do I get it to appear there?

I am confident the answer is dead simple and will make me feel like an idiot....

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Just moved the template folder to (VS2012 installpath)\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\